# Java Generic and inheritage of Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, java-7

It seem that a generic container cannot use a more specific class that the one of a function signature with generic container.

**How can I have a container which use more specific class that the one of the function it is passed to?** Is that possible ? Did I misunderstood  generic in Java ?

Please, look at the code, as it may be easier to understand that the question.

```
    package com.demo;

    public class Entity {
        public String baseField;
    }

    public class ChildEntity extends Entity {
        public String extraField;
    }

    public class EntityContainer<T extends Entity> {
        public T instance;
    }

    public class EntityContainerWithMeta<T extends Entity> extends EntityContainer<T> {
        public String childContainerMetaData;
    }

    public class EntityConsumer<T extends Entity> {
        public void consum(EntityContainer<T> container){

        }
    }

    public class DemoGeneric {

        private class ChildChildEntity extends ChildEntity{
            public String extraExtraField;
        }

        // Objective :
        // - using generic
        // - with a data container that hold a more specific Klass ( Klass extends Entity)
        // - pass it to a less specific consumer ( that consum Entity not Klass)

        // real word use case:
        // Entity is the base class for all my Business Specific Object
        // Container are List<T extends Entity>
        // Consumer are ListAdapter for ListView (extends BaseAdapter) (from Android framework)

        public void demo() {

            // compile: (but then container cannot return ChildEntity with its getter)
            //EntityContainerWithMeta<Entity> demoContainer =
            //new EntityContainerWithMeta<Entity>();

            // don't compile:
            EntityContainerWithMeta<ChildEntity> demoContainer = new EntityContainerWithMeta<ChildEntity>();

            demoContainer.instance = new DemoGeneric.ChildChildEntity();

            EntityConsumer<Entity> consumer = new EntityConsumer<Entity>();

            // here is the problem:
            // required: EntityContainer<Entity>
            // found: EntityContainerWithMeta<ChildEntity>
            consumer.consum(demoContainer);

            // if
            // ChildEntity extends Entity
            // and
            // EntityContainerWithMeta extends EntityContainer
            // why is this not compiling ?
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the answers, I found this article:
http://blog.informatech.cr/2013/03/15/covariance-and-contravariance-in-java/

That explain well the problem mentioned by @kocko and @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: This is not a quirk of Java Generics, it is a fundamental truth. `Container<ChildEntity>` simply *isn't* a `Container<Entity>`, much like a `Hotel<Dog>` isn't a `Hotel<Pet>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this work with array container, which make me think this is a mistake of mine or a limitation of Java Generic. eg: you can set "ChildEntity[] childEntityContainer" with  "Entity[] heterogeneousContainer"

Comment: That's actually because Java's array type system is broken and leads to runtime type check failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following works, although I think it should:

```
public class EntityConsumer {
    public <T extends Entity, M extends EntityContainer<T>> void consum(M container){

    }
}
```

Comment: 1st solution compile !!

Comment: Thanks for checking, I wasn't certain about the second. Is the first what you need?

Comment: I think this is the closest you could get, but I "lost" the `new EntityConsumer**<Entity>**()`

Comment: But `EntityConsumer` will work for all subclasses of Entity, or at least you will be able to access them as `Entity`.

Comment: sur, but I could not "enjoy" a simple getter in my `Consumer` that would return me the good Entity sub-class without casting, nor can I use field of Entity sub-class. (because `instanceof` does not work for generic)

Comment: technically `getClass().isAssignableFrom()` and `getClass().isInstance()` work, although that'd be ugly and kinda ruin the point of generics, unless you also implement a `Visitor` pattern.

Comment: Glad to see that helped in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `consumer` declaration to:

```
EntityConsumer<? extends Entity> consumer = new EntityConsumer<ChildEntity>();
```

> If `ChildEntity extends Entity` and `EntityContainerWithMeta extends EntityContainer` why is this not compiling ?

Because [generics are not implicitly polimorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

Comment: This does not compile neither: method consum in class EntityConsumer<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        consumer.consum(demoContainer);
                ^
  required: EntityContainer<CAP#1>
  found: EntityContainerWithMeta<ChildEntity>
  reason: actual argument EntityContainerWithMeta<ChildEntity> cannot be converted to EntityContainer<CAP#1> by method invocation conversion
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Entity declared in class EntityConsumer
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Entity from capture of ? extends Entity

Comment: Note that, would it compile, I would loose my objective, which is to have a consumer that accept any Entity sub-class.